# How to zip a single file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, zip

I have a CSV file, which is of size 350 MB. I want to zip using python so that I can mail this file.
I tried :

```py
zipfile.ZipFile(file_name+'.zip', mode='w').write(file_name)
```

But it is just renaming CSV file to ZIP file. It's not reducing file size.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a compression method to the constructor:

```
zipfile.ZipFile(filename, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_LZMA)
```

By default, the library uses `ZIP_STORED`, which is uncompressed archive member.

**Source**: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)